# Update Table column using list combination

Tags: python, sql

Hi I would like to update column of table using two list combination. I tried but using where clause, but it check first list completely and then another list. I wan to update using combination so like 1st value list1 & 1st value list2.

```py
+------+----+----------+
| name | Id | ISACTIVE |
+------+----+----------+
| A    |  1 |        1 |
| B    |  2 |        1 |
| C    |  3 |        1 |
| A    |  4 |        1 |
| B    |  5 |        1 |
| C    |  6 |        1 |
+------+----+----------+

by default ISACTIVE is 1

name = ['A','B','C']
ID = [4,5,6]
placeholder= '?' # For SQLite. See DBAPI paramstyle.
placeholders= ', '.join(placeholder for unused in name)
placeholders_1 = ', '.join(placeholder for unused in ID)

allargs = NAME + ID
sql_query = """update prod_staging_db.outward_gstr1_forecast_data SET ISCURRENT = 0 where NAME NOT IN (%s) AND ID NOT IN (%s)"""%(placeholders, placeholders_1)
cursor.execute(sql_query,allargs)
cursor.commit()
```

Output:
2nd run added some record then update status. So output should be like.
It should check A with ID 4 then make status 1 and remaining as 0, so whatever the combination have it make to 1 & and remaining all 0

```
+------+----+----------+
| name | Id | ISACTIVE |
+------+----+----------+
| A    |  1 |        0 |
| B    |  2 |        0 |
| C    |  3 |        0 |
| A    |  4 |        1 |
| B    |  5 |        1 |
| C    |  6 |        1 |
+------+----+----------+
```

Comment: I am not sure about sql. But you can use a zip function in python to simultaneously loop through two lists.

Comment: After zip function  use equal to operator in sql query?

Comment: yup something like `if name, id not in zip(name, id)`

Comment: But how will I pass this to SQL query

Comment: I soled by concatenation. Thanks @UditHariVashisht